# list index out of range when compared against dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a menu system in Python 3.7 using dictionary variables and inputs, new coder just scratching their head

I'm trying to save the users choice in the var **choice** then use **choices** to compare against to scrub inputs, however when ran the code fails consistently with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Nu Voute De Merde\[Redact]\Python Creations\[Redact]\code.py", line 32, in <module>
    if choice == choices[5]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
code:

```
from sys import exit
## Creates the menu using dict vars
menu = {}
menu['1']="Add New Address"
menu['2']="Change Existing Address"
menu['3']="View All Addresses Where Last Name Starts With Letter"
menu['4']="List All Addresses"
menu['5']="Quit"

#Takes the input from the user
choice = int(input("""
 1.Add New Address
 2.Change Existing Address
 3.View All Addresses Where Last Name Starts With Letter
 4.List All Addresses
 5.Quit
    """))
#Sets available options
choices = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]


if choice == choices[1]:
   print (menu['1'])
if choice == choices[2]:
   print (menu['2'])
if choice == choices[3]:
   print (menu['3'])
if choice == choices[4]:
   print (menu['4'])
if choice == choices[5]:
   print (menu['5'])
   exit()
elif choice not in choices:
   print (menu['5'])
   exit()
```

Comment: In your own words, why do you expect `choices[5]` to be valid? What do you expect the result to be?

Comment: Also in your own words: what is the purpose of a `dict`? What is the main advantage it can offer you over using some other container? How might you take advantage of that in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most programming languages, arrays are `0-indexed` so

```
choices = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(choices[0]) # 1
print(choices[4]) # 5
print(choices[5]) # IndexError
```

---

#### Improvement with dict

- there is no need of converting the input to `int`, you directly compare the inputted string to a string from the array
- you'd better directly use the dictionary properties, to check the presence the of key, it avoids to write multiple times about the same stuffs
- you can use the dict content to build the proposition in the `input`

```
## Creates the menu using dict vars
menu = {'1': "Add New Address",
        '2': "Change Existing Address",
        '3': "View All Addresses Where Last Name Starts With Letter",
        '4': "List All Addresses",
        '5': "Quit"}

# Takes the input from the user
choice = input("\n".join('.'.join(pair) for pair in menu.items()) + "\nChoice: ")

if choice == '5' or choice not in menu:
    print(menu['5'])
    exit()
else:
    print(menu[choice])
```

---

#### Improvement with list

As you use numbers as key, you could even store your choices in an array

```
menu = ["Add New Address",
        "Change Existing Address",
        "View All Addresses Where Last Name Starts With Letter",
        "List All Addresses",
        "Quit"]

choice = int(input("\n".join(f"{idx + 1}.{ch}"
                             for idx, ch in enumerate(menu)) + "\nChoice: "))

if choice > 4:
    print(menu[4])
    exit()
else:
    print(menu[choice - 1])
```

Comment: Notably this is different from `menu`, which is a dictionary where you set the keys (here the number 1-5) yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much! You just freed my weekend and took 10 lines out of my code

Comment: @E.V.A. you're welcome, I've add a solution using list and no dict, just for you know. Don't hesitate to accept the answer if it helped you ;)